# Can I ask this question about contact lenses?

Tags: discussion, scope

I always insert my contact lenses while in front of a mirror.  But how would I insert them if no mirror is around?  I've never been able to do that.  Would such a question be on-topic for this site?

Comment: Yes, that would be on-topic. Just ask "How to put on contacts without a mirror".

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed Robert Cartaino has been closing certain "how to" questions as off-topic, so I wasn't sure.